# Making a button background outline disappear after few seconds

Tags: css

the effect im after is the following: the button doesn't look like a button (ie border: none) and when clicked I want the focus outline to fade out after n seconds. 
How can i achieve that? 
Thanks

Comment: add some scripts/ codes, so that we can help you.

Comment: does it have to use javascript? i would prefer only using css if possible

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding a transition. Important to remember is that you need to transition the outline-color, not the outline.

```css
.no-button {
  margin:15px;
  border:none;
}

.no-button:focus {
  outline-color:transparent;
  -webkit-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out 1s;
     -moz-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out 1s;
       -o-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out 1s;
       transition: outline-color .7s ease-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<button class="no-button">This is no button</button>
```

The first time (`.7s`) is the `duration`, the second one (`1s`) is the `delay`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting such an effect border is better than outline and I played a little bit with it for you and the result is as follow:

```css
button {
  background: border-box linear-gradient(#841518, #4C0C00) no-repeat;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Sans;
  border: none;
  transition: border-color 0.7s 0.2s;
  border-width: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80px;
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button:focus {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click here</button>
```